# C# EWS Delete Appointment doesn't work

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to delete `Appointments` via the `EWS` but it doesn't work. I have the following code:

```
private void deleteAppointment(object obj)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@place.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    ItemId ii = (ItemId)obj;

    Appointment a = Appointment.Bind(service, ii);
    try
    {
        a.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
    }
    catch (ServiceResponseException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The User that is logged in on the machine(me) is a Owner of the Calender from the `user` Address. But if I try to delete the `Appointment` the `Exception` is "Object cannot be deleted". The `ItemId` is correct. If I use the `user` Address as `Credentials` it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems, you need write access to the DeletedItems folder in addition to your access to the Calendar folder. If you don't want to add folder perms to the Deleted Items folder, you can use either DeleteMode.HardDelete or DeleteMode.SoftDelete.